# How to continue to a previous loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two loops in my code and I want the second one to continue (go to the first one) basically restarting the program.

## first loop

```
words = []

while True:
    new_item = input("Enter words to select from and type END when you have entered all words: ")
    if new_item == "END":
        break
    words.append(new_item)

chosen = random.choice(words)
length = len(words)
print("Your list is", length, "items long\n" "The randomly chosen word is: ", chosen)
```

## second loop

```
while True:
    option = input("again? (y / n): ")
    if option == "y":
        continue 
    else:
        break
```

at the moment if the user presses "y" the loop will continue and as to input an answer again. However, i want it to continue to the first loop(restart the program).
if there is any solution or an easier way to do this, please help.

p.s new to python

Comment: wrap each one in a function, it will be easier

Comment: You have two main options, either put each in a function, and call the first function from the second. Or you could wrap your entire code into a loop which repeatedly runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend discarding the second while loop for simplicity sake (you seem to have initiated it for the sake of returning to the first one anyway), and nesting your first loop inside a bigger, condition controlled one. Define `option` outside the "master" with a default value. While `option` holds this value, you will continue to loop.

```
option = 'y'

while option.lower() in {'y', 'ye', 'yes'}:  
    words = []
    while True:
        new_item = input("Enter words to select from and type END when you have entered all words: ")
        if new_item == "END":
            break
        words.append(new_item)

    chosen = random.choice(words)
    length = len(words)
    print("Your list is", length, "items long\n" "The randomly chosen word is: ", chosen)

    option = input("again? (y / n): ")
```

Comment: This works however, it does not clear the list (words) so the previous words come in as well. any way to clear it when it loops?

Comment: @COLDSPEED works! Thanks for the help. Just wondering any reason you added the .lower() string?

Comment: @HelpPlease If the user inputs 'Y', or 'YES', then your code will not be able to catch it, if you are only looking for 'y' and 'yes'. Remember string comparisons are case sensitive. You'd _want_ to make sure you are comparing the same strings, even if they are in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Define your game as a function `game()` and call it if in your "second" while loop. continue the loop to call `game()` agian if user input "y" and break if user input "n".

```
def game():
  words = []
  while True:
      new_item = input("Enter words to select from and type END when you have entered all words: ")
      if new_item == "END":
          break
      words.append(new_item)

  chosen = random.choice(words)
  length = len(words)
  print("Your list is", length, "items long\n" "The randomly chosen word is: ", chosen)


while True:
    game()
    option = input("again? (y / n): ")
    if option == "y":
        continue 
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Nest the loops. You are emulating a do-while loop in python, which doesn't have native do while syntax. The following is a very common.

```
while True:

   # makes empty list for words.
   words = []

    # user enters n words before user enters END
    while True:

        new_item = input("Enter words to select from and type END when you have entered all words: ")

        if new_item == "END":
            # breaks out of inner loop and shows output
            break

        words.append(new_item)

    # show output
    chosen = random.choice(words)
    length = len(words)
    print("Your list is", length, "items long\n" "The randomly chosen word is: ", chosen)

    # ask user for again
    option = input("again? (y / n): ")

    if option == "y":  
        # returns to top of outer loop, and empty words array  
        continue

    else:
        # ends outer loop
        break
```

Comment: This is not working. you need to clear the list `words[]` otherwise when user play again it is still using the same list

Comment: use add line words = [] between print( ... ) and option = .... Or you can add it to the top of the outer loop, b/c continue will send execution there before entering the inner loop.